# If $A\lhd B\lhd C$ with $[C:A]=p^n$, is there $D\lhd A$ with $D\subset C$ and $D/A$ a finite $p$-group?

Tags: group-theory, p-groups

Let $A$ be a (possibly infinite) group.

Consider subgroups $C\lhd B\lhd A$, and assume that $A/B$ and $B/C$ are both finite $p$-groups.

Is there necessarily a subgroup $D$ normal in $A$ and contained in $C$ such that $A/D$ is a finite $p$-group?

This is related to another question:

> [If the subgroup $H$ of $G$ is open in pro-$p$ topology, does it inherit the pro-$p$ topology?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1331520/if-the-subgroup-h-of-g-is-open-in-pro-p-topology-does-it-inherit-the-pro)

Comment: @ZevChonoles I don't think he requires strict containment.

Comment: So really the question is whether the intersection of the conjugates of $C$ will have a finite index which is a power of $p$.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft: Yes, you are correct, this is what I'm asking (the normal core of $C$ in $A$ has finite index for sure, the question is whether it is a power of $p$)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the core of $C$ in $A$ has finite index in $A$, we can assume without loss of generality that $A$ is finite.

But then we can just choose $D=O^p(A)$, which is the smallest normal subgroup of $A$ such that the quotient is a $p$-group or, alternatively, the subgroup of $A$ generated by the $p'$-elements of $A$.

So the answer is yes.

Comment: I understand the passage to finite groups. What are $p'$-elements?

Comment: I'm confused. I'm not sure why this $D$ is contained in $C$.

Comment: Yes, I've replaced $G$ by $A$. A $p'$-element is an element whose order is not divisible by $p$. It is not difficult to see that if you define $D$ to be the subgroup of $A$ generated by its $p'$-elements, then $A/D$ is a $p$-group and, if $E$ is any normal subgroup of $A$ such that $A/E$ is a $p$-group, then $D \le E$, so $D$ is the unique smallest normal sugbroup whose quotient is a $p$-group.

Comment: Ok. What remains for me is to understand why all $p'$-elements are contained in $A$. Probably raising them to appropriate powers until they're in $B$ and then in $A$ will work. I'll think about it.

Comment: Yes, it seems to work. Let $x$ be a $p'$-element of $A$. Then after raising $x$ to a certain power of $p$ we get an element of $B$, and after raising again to some power of $p$ we get an element of $C$. So $x^{p^m}$ is an element of $C$. Now we find the inverse of $p^m$ modulo the order of $x$, denote it by $t$, and see that $x=x^{tp^m}$ is an element of $C$.

Comment: Is that the argument you had in mind?

Comment: In the answer itself, you say "largest normal subgroup". This should be "smallest".

Comment: Yes, I meant smallest not largest.